Elliptic boundary value problem with time dependency
I am looking at an elliptic boundary value problem for an open set $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ that is solved over a time interval $(0,T)$ with $T>0$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
\Delta_{x}v(x,t) &= 0,  &&\left(x,t\right)\in \Omega\times(0,T), \\
v(x,t) &= u(x,t),  &&\left(x,t\right)\in \partial \Omega\times(0,T),
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
and I wonder about the existence and regularity of a solution $v$ to this problem, assuming we can choose $u$ however we like. I know a solution exists on the boundary $\partial(\Omega\times(0,T))$, but does it also exist for the above problem?
